# Dificuldade em pegar determinado tipo de retorno em c#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp

Tenho um retorno que envio via Ajax que ele retorna na URL da seguinte maneira:

```
"http://localhost:11910/ProtocoloExterno/Inserir?itensContrato[0][id]=4&itensContrato[0][valorUsado]=150000,00&itensContrato[1][id]=9&itensContrato[1][valorUsado]=10050,00&contrato=4100001124&codigoParceiro=7900325&nomeParceiro=ORANGE COTE D%23IVOIRE S.A.&areaReclamacao=&codigoPatrimonial=5411050&operadora=Móvel&statusObra=&nFRN=&endereco=Rua Ursulina de Melo&estado=AM&cidade=78&descItem=desc&icms=15100,00&ipi=410,00&contaContabil=Capital não chamado&ordemInterna=Rua Ursulina de Melo&quantidade=1&valorUnitario=160050,00&valorTotal=160050,00&numeroPedido=11000110&itemPedido=10&observacao="
```

Quando eu coloco `Request.QueryString["endereco"];` por exemplo, pego bonitinho, a maior dificuldade é pegar os dados que envio a partir de um array via ajax.

Trecho que envio via javascript

```
$(document).on('click', "#btnSalvar", function () {

    var erros = 0;
    $("div").find('*').each(function () {
        var classe = $(this).attr("class");
        if (classe !== undefined) {
            var numItems = $('.has-error').length;
            if (numItems > 0) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                //debugger;
                itensContrato = [];

               $("input:checked").each(function () {
                    var id = $(this).data("id");
                    var valorUsado = $(".txt" + id).val();
                    itensContrato.push({ id: id, valorUsado: valorUsado })

                });

               debugger;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'Inserir',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    data: {
                        itensContrato: itensContrato,
                        contrato: $("#cmbContrato").val(),
                        codigoParceiro: $("#lblCodigoParceiro").html(),
                        nomeParceiro: $("#lblNomeParceiro").html(),
                        tipoContrato: $("#cmbTipoContrato").val(),
                        areaReclamacao: $("#lblAreaReclamacao").html(),
                        codigoPatrimonial: $("#txtCodigoPatrimonial").val(),
                        operadora: $("#cmbOperadora").val(),
                        statusObra: $("#cmbStatusObra").val(),
                        nFRN: $("#txtNFnr").val(),
                        endereco: $("#txtEndereço").val(),
                        estado: $("#cmbEstado").val(),
                        cidade: $("#cmbCidade").val(),
                        descItem: $("#txtDescricaoItem").val(),
                        icms: $("#txtICMS").val(),
                        ipi: $("#txtIPI").val(),
                        contaContabil: $("#lblContaContabil").html(),
                        ordemInterna: $("#txtOrdemInterna").val(),
                        quantidade: $("#txtQuantidade").val(),
                        valorUnitario: $("#txtValorUnitario").val(),
                        valorTotal: $("#txtValorTotal").val(),
                        numeroPedido: $("#txtNumeroPedido").val(),
                        itemPedido: $("#txtItemPedido").val(),
                        observacao: $("#txtObservacao").val()
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Se eu indico um parametro como itensContrato[0][id] ele consegue pegar o valor certinho, mas como eu não sei quantos itensContrato tem, queria percorrer a url de tal forma que eu achasse a quantidade de itensContrato[pos][id] e itensContrato[pos][valorUtilizado]

Comment: É necessário ser via `GET`? Caso seja asp.MVC, você pode utilizar no lugar de `Request.QueryString`, parâmetros dentro do método chamado na controladora. Exemplo: `public ActionResult NomeDoMetodoNoController (string [] itensContrato, string contrato, string codigoParceiro, string nomeParceiro, ...) { }`. Vale ressaltar que os tipos de parâmetro vão de acordo com o parse feito.

Comment: @DanielNicodemos mas minha dificuldade mesmo é pegar eles via o Request.QueryString

Comment: teria como postar seu controller?

Comment: Vou correr o risco de ser ridicularizado, mas 
`itensContrato[0][id]=4` não me parece uma sintaxe aceitável para querystring. Se você quer passar um array de objetos compostos, sugiro que faça via POST

Comment: @DanielNicodemos desculpe os anos de demora, eu só preciso saber como pegar essa sintaxe de itensContrato

Comment: @gabrielfalieri Como você está fazendo com o `QueryString` que recebe? Está transformando em uma classe ou está pegando os valores na unha por assim dizer?

Comment: @rodrigogq na unha rs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tenho algumas sugestões pra você.

Primeiro, nunca faça tratamento de JSON na unha. Do seu lado do C#, crie uma classe que tem exatamente os mesmos dados do JSON do lado do JavaScript.
Exemplo:

```
public class ItemContrato { 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ValorUsado { get; set; }
}

public class RetornoJson { 
    public ItemContrato [] ItensContrato { get; set; }
    public int CodigoParceiro { get; set; }
    public string NomeParceiro { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Isso se chama trabalho com modelos de dados.
Assim que o seu modelo refletir exatamente os dados que você está enviando, você pode usar este código:

```
string jsonResultado = Request.QueryString...
var resultado = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RetornoJson>(jsonResultado);
```

Tente brincar um pouco a variavel `jsonResultado` para você ver a mágica.
Precisa instalar o pacote Newtonsoft.Json primeiro.
Depois que tudo for objetos no seu C#, você não precisa mais ficar se preocupando com a conversão em si.. e adicionar e remover elementos fica mais fácil depois.

Nesta documentação você vai achar mais exemplos: [Deserialize an Object](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm)

Daí vai ser fácil usar os dados:

```
var qtdContratos = resultado.ItensContrato.Count; // só não esqueça de ver se está null antes disso
foreach(var itemContrato in resultado.ItensContrato) {}
```

A segunda dica é a forma que você está passando os dados para o servidor. Ele não segue o padrão JSON. Quando trabalhamos com valores numéricos, não existe vírgula, como você está usando. Toda string precisa ter um "scape".

Veja este exemplo: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON

Depois que você começou a ver o que é um JSON, tente ver se sua QueryString está retornando um JSON válido. Senão enfrentará problemas.

Comment: O que acontece, eu estou usando esse Request.QueryString na unha pois tenho passar esses parametros para protocolo.Campo com  Protocolo protocolo = new Protocolo();
Esse cara atenderia o problema?

Comment: Se você montar um JSON igualzinha a classe `Protocolo` do lado do servidor, com os mesmos nomes usado na classe também no lado do Json (igual o exemplo na documentação que te passei), o JsonConvert.DeserializeObject vai fazer o new Protocolo() internamente pra você já, só que a diferença é que virá com os valores do JavaScript já preenchido.

Comment: Acontece que não é iguaaalzinha, são campos especificos que mando via javascript

Comment: Neste caso, recomendo que você crie outra classe com o nome `ModeloProtocolo`, e coloque nela o que você tem no JavaScript. Você pode ter vários modelos diferentes para usar de formar diferente. Tem gente que divide em pastas dentro do projeto. Tem projeto com a pasta `Models` \ `RequestModels` \ `ResponseModels`, etc.

Comment: @gabrielfalieri Pode parecer que vai dar um trabalhinho fazer isso. Mas tente uma vez para você ver como facilita em muito. Faz um projeto teste de console de linha de comando só com uma classe mesmo. Passa uma string na mão (um json) e tenta deserializar para um objeto. Depois que pegar o jeito você implementa pra valer a solução.

Comment: caraaaaaaalhooooo que facil, pqp