# Pegar retorno de url c#

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net

Eu preciso pegar um retorno de um ajax que mando.

A URL me retorna algo do tipo:

```
http://localhost:11910/ProtocoloExterno/Inserir?itensContrato%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=1&itensContrato%5B0%5D%5BvalorUsado%5D=15110%2C10&itensContrato%5B1%5D%5Bid%5D=2&itensContrato%5B1%5D%5BvalorUsado%5D=111%2C00&contrato=4100001060&codigoParceiro=7900321&nomeParceiro=MTN%20AFGHANISTAN&areaReclamacao=&codigoPatrimonial=4000014000&operadora=Fixo&statusObra=bis&nFRN=1011000510&endereco=Rua%20Ursulina%20de%20Melo&estado=AL&cidade=1651&descItem=Descricao%20de%20teste&icms=1&ipi=10&contaContabil=Capital%20n%C3%A3o%20chamado&ordemInterna=15101000&quantidade=10&valorUnitario=15221%2C10&valorTotal=15221%2C10&numeroPedido=100040&itemPedido=10&observacao=
```

Quando eu coloco o `Request.QueryString["valorTotal"]` por exemplo, funciona perfeitamente, se eu coloco `Request.QueryString["itensContrato[0][id]"]` e `Request.QueryString["itensContrato[0][valorUsado]"]` também funciona perfeitamente, só que esse itensContrato pode um como poder ter 15, queria alguma forma que percorresse a url verificando esses valores idependetemente da quantidade de itens que tiver.

Obrigado desde já

Comment: você realmente pretende passar esse conteúdo todo por GET???

Comment: sim, necessito de passar via get

Comment: qual é a versão do .net? Mvc padrão ou WebApi?

Comment: estou usando o 4.6.1

Comment: Outra coisa, e se eu passar via post?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo e ae?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Dificuldade em pegar determinado tipo de retorno em c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/298684/dificuldade-em-pegar-determinado-tipo-de-retorno-em-c)

Answer (score 0):

Para pegar o total de itens:

```
int? total  = Request.QueryString.GetValues("itensContrato")?.Count();
```

Segue exemplo para pegar o `array` de valores e percorrê-los.

```
string[] array = Request.QueryString.GetValues("itensContrato");

if(array != null)
{
    foreach (var valor in array)
    {
        string v = valor;
    }
}
```